# Getting to work rock, paper, scissors game in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a rock, paper, scissors python program, but I cant get it to work. Can anybody help me? PS: I am using Python 3.5

I start by importing `random` and telling Python to run different programs depending on the result from `random.randint(1,3)`

```
import random

def rps():
    computer_choice = random.randint(1,3)
    if computer_choice == 1:
        computer_choice_rock()
    elif computer_choice == 2:
        computer_choice_paper()
    elif computer_choice == 3:
        computer_choice_scissors()
```

I make the programs it should run under this text. I think this might be the source of the errors.

```
def computer_choice_rock():
    use_choice = raw_input("1 for Rock, 2 for paper, 3 for Scissors: ")
    if user_choice == "1":
        print ("You Tie. You chose Rock, and the computer chose Rock.")
        try_again()
    if user_choice == "2":
        print ("you win. You chose Paper, and the computer chose Rock.")
        try_again()
    if user_choice == "3":
        print ("you lose. You chose Scissors, and the computer chose Rock.")
        try_again()
    else:
        print ("try again")
        computer_choice_rock()

def computer_choice_paper():
    use_choice = raw_input("1 for Rock, 2 for paper, 3 for Scissors: ")
    if user_choice == "1":
        print ("you lose. You chose Rock, and the computer chose Paper.")
        try_again()
    if user_choice == "2":
        print ("you tie. You chose Paper, and the computer chose Paper.")
        try_again()
    if user_choice == "3":
        print ("you win. You chose Scissors, and the computer chose Paper.")
        try_again()
    else:
        print ("try again")
        computer_choice_paper()

def computer_choice_scissors():
    use_choice = raw_input("1 for Rock, 2 for paper, 3 for Scissors: ")
    if user_choice == "1":
        print ("you win. You chose Rock, and the computer chose Scissors.")
        try_again()
    if user_choice == "2":
        print ("you lose. You chose Paper, and the computer chose Scissors.")
        try_again()
    if user_choice == "3":
        print ("you tie. You chose Scissors, and the computer chose Scissors.")
        try_again()
    else:
        print ("try again")
        computer_choice_rock()


def try_again():
    choice = raw_input("Would you like to play again? y/n ")
    if choice == "y" or choice == "yes" or choice =="Y" or choice == "Yes":
        rps()
    elif choice == "n":
        print ("Thanks for playing")
        quit()
    else:
        print ("Try again")
        try_again()
rps()
```

error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jakob/Desktop/rps.py", line 68, in <module>
    rps()
  File "C:/Users/Jakob/Desktop/rps.py", line 8, in rps
    computer_choice_paper()
  File "C:/Users/Jakob/Desktop/rps.py", line 28, in computer_choice_paper
    user_choice = raw_input("1 for Rock, 2 for paper, 3 for Scissors: ")
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

Comment: You have a typo: you probably intended to assign `user_choice` (instead of `use_choice`) to `raw_input()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking raw_input as `use_choice` and comparing `user_choice`.
The variable names are different.

Comment: That wasnt the only thing wrong. but thanks for the help i am one step closer now :)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jakob/Desktop/rps.py", line 68, in <module>
    rps()
  File "C:/Users/Jakob/Desktop/rps.py", line 8, in rps
    computer_choice_paper()
  File "C:/Users/Jakob/Desktop/rps.py", line 28, in computer_choice_paper
    user_choice = raw_input("1 for Rock, 2 for paper, 3 for Scissors: ")
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: For python3, use `input()` instead of `raw_input`.

Comment: Thank you again now it just says "invalid syntax" :).

Comment: a window pops up where it says "invalid syntax" there is no error post sorry.

Comment: its takes me to the first line after "def computer_choice_rock():" after input

Comment: i found out what i was doing wrong but there came up a few more error posts

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jakob/Desktop/rps.py", line 68, in <module>
    rps()
  File "C:/Users/Jakob/Desktop/rps.py", line 10, in rps
    computer_choice_scissors()
  File "C:/Users/Jakob/Desktop/rps.py", line 43, in computer_choice_scissors
    user_choice = input()("1 for Rock, 2 for paper, 3 for Scissors: ")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: could you maybe give me the code so i could try it maybe i just wrote something wrong.

Comment: thanks for all Your help i will compare the 2 and try to find out what i did wrong

Comment: Yeah i know but i still want to know what i did wrong i am trying to learn. i am really impressed though of how good you are With python